# ImageViews sometimes not displaying in FrameLayout activity

Tags: android, imageview, drawable, android-2.2-froyo

The top level layout in my activity is a framelayout. I have completed, debugged and tested this app and it works exactly like it should in all respects on my g1 and  on various emulators. But on 3.7-inch displays running 2.1+, some imageviews packed in a linearlayout
are **periodically** not visible. I know that they are there because you can touch and drag them with effect in the app. So I assume somehow
they have gotten under the SurfaceView that is the main component of the app. This is apparently so even though the SurfaceView is declared in the xml prior to the LinearLayout.  However, the ImageViews IN the LinearLayout are added programmatically towards the end of onCreate().

Framelayout stacks everything that is added to it, one on top of the other--the only way you will see more than one child of a frame layout is if they are smaller than the screen and are placed apart from eachother.

Oddly, sometimes the imageviews ARE visible--it is random. Anyway, I've been trying to combat this with framelayout.bringChildToFront(View v) on the linearlayout without success.

I wonder if anyone has any insight into how the behavior could be random like that, and how I should code these imageviews
to keep this from happening, and why the problem appears only to occur on 3.7 vs 3.2 inch screens (as it happens, the two 3.2-inch screens were both htc, so vendor might be factor too).

[edit] Actually, I've determined that this is a 2.2 issue, not a screen size (or even vendor) issue.  Can't ensure that ImageViews added to a framelayout with a SurfaceView 
in it will appear on top of the surfaceview.  I ran some tests in the respective onDraw() methods and the imageviews are 'visible' (0), and nothing does anything to the alpha of the drawables, which are there as well at ondraw(). [/edit]

Any insight would be welcomed.

Ken T.

Answer (score 0):

I had to draw the drawables in SurfaceView's doDraw() method, and I had to change the file names of the drawables.  I think this was a case of malicious code somewhere.  I had to scrap the ImageViews and transfer my touch-handling code elsewhere.